# Python: PySerial disconnecting from device randomly

Tags: python, pyserial, stability

I have a process that runs data acquisition using PySerial. It's working fine now, but there's a weird thing I had to do to make it work continuously, and I'm not sure this is normal, so I'm asking this question.

**What happens:** It looks like that the connection drops now and then! Around once every 30-60 minutes, with big error bars (could go for hours and be OK, but sometimes happens often).

**My question**: Is this standard?

**My temporary solution**: I wrote a simple "reopen" function that looks like this:

```
def ReopenDevice(devObject):
    try:
        devObject.close()
        devObject.open()
    except Exception as e:
        print("Error while trying to connect to device " + devObject.port + ". The error says: " + str(e))
        time.sleep(2)
```

And what I do is that if data pulling fails for 2 minutes, I reopen the device with this function, and it continues working well with no problems.

**My program model**: It's a GUI program, where the user clicks something like "Start", and that button does some preparations and runs a function through `multiprocessing.Process()` that starts with:

```
devObj = serial.Serial()
#... other params
devObj.open()
```

and that function then runs a while loop that keeps polling data with something like:

```
bytesToRead = devObj.inWaiting()
if bytesToRead != 0:
    buffer = decodeString(devObj.read(bytesToRead))
    #process buffer and push it to a list...
```

The way I know that the problem happened, is that `devObj.inWaiting()` Keeps returning zero... no matter how much data there's on the device!

Is this behavior expected and should always be considered whether it happens or doesn't happen?

Comment: It's really hard to say what's the problem since it can be related to configuration issues (baudRate/Parity) or even to the device it self, One question is do you have a sleep at your loop? maybe you are "flooding" the device with requests and it can handle it.

Comment: @KobiK Actually no. I don't `sleep` in the loop. Because I want to pull all the data available as fast as possible, while the device queues only 16KB of data.

Comment: If it's only `inWaiting()` then it shouldn't be an issue but if you send commands that's a different case, As i said hard to answer as it may be hardware issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem reduced a lot after not calling `inWaiting()` very frequently. Anyway, I kept the reconnect part to ensure that my program never fails. Thanks for "Kobi K" for suggesting the possible cause of the problem.